# CodeIgniter a.tag onclick if else event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, onclick

I am trying to create a PHP if else statement from an anchor tag onclick event through my CodeIgniter header.php view. Below is the HTML

```
<li><a onclick='$(".titles li:eq(1)").trigger("click")' href="#">About Us</a></li>
```

My "About Us" section is the second tab on the home.php view. Currently, if I'm on the home page this works great, however, if I'm not on the home page this anchor tag when clicked will move to the second tab if there is any tabbed data on the page. How can I get the anchor tag to redirect to the home view and open the 2nd tab if I'm currently not on the home view? Do I need to send an ajax post to all of the Controllers that aren't the Home Controller? From there use an if else statement in each Controller saying

New HTML:

```
<li><a onclick='ajaxAbout(pass current URL)' href="#">About Us</a></li>
```

Every Controller that's not the home page:

```
    public function ajaxURL(){
       if (on home page) {
          echo '$(".titles li:eq(1)").trigger("click")';
       }else{
          redirect to home page and pass data to open second tab;
       }
    }
```

Ajax

```
function ajaxAbout(current url)
{
  var currentURL = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
     url:'<?=base_url()?>/ajaxURL',
     method: 'post',
     data: {currentURL: currentURL},
     dataType: 'json',
     success:function(data){
            $('#resultAjax').html(data);
     }
  });
 });
```

Comment: As non-resolving advice, I would put a listener in my javascript code, not inline events; these bloat your markup and make it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

In header file:

```
<?php
$currntClass = $this->router->fetch_class();
$currntMethod = $this->router->fetch_method();

$about_us_lnk = 'javascript:;';$about_us_cls = "about-us-nav";
if($currntClass != 'Home'){
    $about_us_lnk = $this->config->item('base_url').'?nav=about_us';
    $about_us_cls = "";
}?>
```

About Us Link also in header file:

```
<li><a class="<?=$about_us_cls?>" href="<?=$about_us_lnk?>">About Us</a></li>
```

footer.php - Function inside script tag:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('?nav') > -1){
 if(window.location.href.indexOf('about_us') > -1){
     $(".mn-page .titles li:eq(1)").trigger("click");
     
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('.mn-page').offset().top - 100
     }, 'slow');
 }
}

$('.about-us-nav').on('click', function(){
  $(".mn-page .titles li:eq(1)").trigger("click");
     
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.mn-page').offset().top - 100
  }, 'slow');
});
```

Index.php (added mn-page to class name):

```
<ul class="tabs mn-page">
```